# How to display all child/sub pages from all parent pages?

Tags: page-template

Hi
I would like to display all child pages from all parents pages. Not from specific parent!
and I would like to display them as random.

The code I used currently :

```
$posts=get_posts('child_of='.$post>ID.'paged=2&posts_per_page=1&sort_column=post_date &sort_order=desc&showposts=3$orderby=rand&post_type=page');
```

Now if I use random as orderby then it shows all parents and child pages. But what I'm doing now use orderby=post_date and limit the number of posts as 3 so now i'm getting 3 child pages which I wanted, but I add more page as child then it won't appear, because I'm not using random.

Haven't found any template tag for child page display.

The full code is follows:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?/*php $post=query_posts('showposts=3'); */?> 

<?php $post=query_posts('post_type=page&orderby=rand&posts_per_page=3'); ?>

<?/*php $posts =get_posts('paged=2&posts_per_page=1
&orderby=rand&showposts=3&post_type=page'); foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); */?>

<?php $posts = get_posts('child_of='.$post->ID.'
  $paged=2&posts_per_page=1&sort_column=post_date &sort_order=desc&showposts=3
  $orderby=post_date&post_type=page'); // important

foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>

    <?php static $count1 = 0; if ($count1 == "2") { ?>
    <div id="lastcolumn">
    <div id="entry">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php get_post_thumbnail(); ?>" /></a>
   <div id="entry-text">
   <?php $entry = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'additional_text', true); ?>

   <h1><?php the_title(); ?> /&nbsp</h1><p><?php echo $entry; ?></p>
 </div>
</div>
</div>


  <?php } elseif ($count1 == "3") { break; } else { ?>
  <div id="column">
  <div id="entry">
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php get_post_thumbnail(); ?>" /></a>
  <div id="entry-text">
  <?php $entry = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'additional_text', true); ?>
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?> /&nbsp</h1><p><?php echo $entry; ?></p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<?php $count1++; } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any help or clue wiill be great favor.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a random thought. query for ALL pages, but exclude the parents. Something like this maybe?

```
query_posts( array( 'post__not_in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 ) , 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'rand' , 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );
```